# Как изменить реальный url материала?

Tags: joomla, joomla3

Вывод новостей осуществляется стандартными средствами Joomla.
В итоге при открытии конкретного материала новости url получается вида: **syte.ru/index.php/название_новости**
Как можно заменить index.php на **нужный мне текст** (конкретно это будет алиас главного пункта меню, но в зависимости от меню, будет меняться).
С **index.php** у меня контент вокруг новости отображается не тот (относится к другому меню), по этому мне надо указывать нужное меню.

Answer (score 0):

**Раз.** Как вариант использование нескольких меню, имею в виду модулей.
**Два** - это отказаться от index.php в url - в настройках сайта, блок "Настройки SEO" нужно включить параметры "Включить SEF (ЧПУ)" и "Перенаправление URL" - с последним внимательнее, нужно включить .htaccess. Это избавит от index.php.
**Три** - использовать категории. Материалы в определённой категории как раз-таки будут иметь url типа syte.ru/**название_категории**/название_новости.